# Delete every other line starting with a 1

Tags: awk, sed, text-files, delete-row

I can find sed solutions to delete all lines in a text file starting with a '1' as well as solutions to delete every other line of all the lines in the text file but I want to combine the two.. of all the lines starting with '1' delete every other one of them and keep the other lines that do not start with a 1.

So if I have a text file:

```
1, 1
1, 2
2, 3
3, 4
4, 5
2, 6
1, 7
3, 8
1, 9
4, 10
```

I want the output to be:

```
1, 1
2, 3
3, 4
4, 5
2, 6
1, 7
3, 8
4, 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in awk:

```
awk -F, '!($1 == 1 && n++ % 2)' file
```

`-F,` means use comma as the field separator, so the two numbers on each line will be the variables `$1` and `$2`.

awk will print the line if the last thing it evaluates is true. The `!` negates the contents of the parentheses, so in order to print, the contents must be false.

If the first field isn't `1`, short-circuiting takes place, as `(false && anything)` will always be false. This means that the second half after the `&&` will not be evaluated.

If `$1 == 1`, then the second half is evaluated. As `n` is being used for the first time in a numeric context, it will assume the value `0`. The modulo operation `n % 2` will return `0` (false) for even numbers and `1` (true) for odd numbers. Using the increment `n++` means that the result will alternate between true and false.

You may prefer the reverse logic, which would be:

```
awk -F, '$1 != 1 || ++n % 2' file
```

The `||` is also short-circuiting, so if the first value isn't `1` then the line gets printed. Otherwise, the second half is evaluated. This time, the increment goes before the `n` so that the first value of `n` is `1`, making the expression evaluate to true.

Either way, the output is:

```
1, 1
2, 3
3, 4
4, 5
2, 6
1, 7
3, 8
4, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^1/{x;/./{z;x;d};x;h}' file
```

Use the hold space to toggle the deletion of lines beginning with `1`.

An alternative:

```
sed '/^1/{:a;n;//d;ba}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
awk '$1=="1," && !(f=f?0:1) {next} 1' file
1, 1
2, 3
3, 4
4, 5
2, 6
1, 7
3, 8
4, 10
```

`$1=="1,"` Test if first field is `1`
`f=f?0:1` Flop the `f` between `0` and  `1` for every time `$1=="1,"` is true
`!(...)` True if `f` is `0`

Comment: This worked on my small example but I tried on a larger set with many more rows and columns and it failed

Comment: @user3662220 Then please update your original post with none working data and I will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `awk`-based solution without requiring any modulo math whatsoever :

```
[ngm]awk 'FS~NF||_*=--_' FS='^1'
```

|

```
1, 1
2, 3
3, 4
4, 5
2, 6
1, 7
3, 8
4, 10
```

This leverages the interesting property that `x *= --x` generates an alternating sequence of `1`s and `0`s that never converges and never diverges.